# Understanding DirectX

Tags: c#, directx

```
//          Draw primitives
        device.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format;
        device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan, 4, verts);

        device.Transform.World = Matrix.RotationY(angle += 0.05f);

        //          Draw primitives
        device.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format;
        device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan, 4, verts);

        device.Transform.World = Matrix.RotationZ(angle += 0.05f);
```

I can't understand Transform.World.
How I understand (it would be logical) You draw first Triangle and it rotates Y... Then you draw second triangle and it would rotate both triangles to Z-axis.. This code works => One triangle is rotating only Y, second only Z. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the first triangle is rotated along the Z-axis, is because you set the rotation the previous function, and it is preserved until you change it. After you drew that, you changed it to be a rotation along the Y-axis, and then you draw the second triangle. Then you set the matrix to be a rotation along the Z-axis again, and the whole process starts over.

You are not adding to the rotation that was previously in `device.Transform.World`, you're simply resetting it. If you want to add them together, you would have to multiply them.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform matrix multpilication if you want to combine multiple transformations. That is, your last command should be `device.Transform.World *= Matrix.RotationZ(angle += 0.05f);`. Your code simply replaces rotation along Y with rotation along Z-axis. And, btw., you should first apply the tranformation, and only then render primitives (not the other way around).

You should be able to find many detailed transformation tutorials online.